# Prove or disprove $3(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2)\ge (ab+bc+ac)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\ge 0$ Prove or disprove
$$3(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2)\ge (ab+bc+ac)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$

I have try use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$3(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)\ge (ab+bc+ca)^2$$

But $ab+bc+ca\le a^2+b^2+c^2$

Comment: Is question  to prove last sentence?

Comment: If you fix $b$ and $c$, then the LHS is a quadratic in $a$ but the RHS is a cubic, so the statement must be false.

Comment: Disproving is easy, set $a=2,b=c=1$. Unless you want to prove the flipped inequality is true.

Comment: @Macavity You are wrong. The flipped inequality is also wrong. Try $c=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given inequality is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{sym}(3a^2 b^2-a^2 bc -a^3 b)\geq 0 $$
that does not hold for $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$. However, a similar inequality, namely
$$ \sum_{sym}(a^4-2a^3 b+a^2 bc)\geq 0 $$

holds by [Schur's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality) with $t=2$.